# Line Breaks Stripped when using API with Powershell

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

Have a problem using the Salesforce Soap API with Powershell. Seems like when we push a string up thats supposed to have line breaks, they're stripped when encoded to XML.

Need a way to escape the XML encoding for our line breaks.

So far have tried;

```
    `n, `r, /n, \n, \\n, \\r, \\r\\n, \\\\n, \u0032, &#x000d;, &#x000a;, &#10;, \0x0A
```

Example of what we've built;

```
    $uri = "C:\scripts\Salesforce\wsdl.jsp.xml"
    $loginname = "apiaccess@somedomain.com"
    $password = "password"
    $token =  "token" 
    $passwordandtoken = $password + $token

    $login = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Namespace sforce -UseDefaultCredential

    $loginResult = $login.login($loginname, $passwordandtoken)

    $username = "USER@somedomain.com" 

    $service = New-Object sforce.SforceService
    $service.Url = $loginResult.serverUrl
    $service.SessionHeaderValue = New-Object sforce.SessionHeader
    $service.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = $loginResult.sessionId

    $sfuser = $null
    $user = get-aduser $shortusername -properties name, Title, Telephonenumber, mail, physicalDeliveryOfficeName 

    $Signature = "USER \n Surname" #Any Linebreaks here are Stripped during upload.

    $query =  "FIND {" + $username + "} IN All FIELDS RETURNING User (ID, Name, Username, Signature)"

    $sfuser = $service.search($query).searchRecords.record | select ID, Name, Username, Signature
    if ($sfuser -ne $null){
            $userupdate = new-object sforce.User
            $userupdate.id = $sfuser.id
            $userupdate.Signature = $signature
            $service.update($userupdate)
            $sfuser = $service.search($query).searchRecords.record | select ID, Name, Username, Signature
    }

    $service.logout()
```

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: How about the .NET `Environment.NewLine` member? Any difference there?

Comment: Thanks Mark. Changed the code to look like this;

    `$Signature = ("USER " + [system.environment]::NewLine + " Surname")`

Still getting stripped though.

Comment: Have you attempted to wrap the contents of that node with a CDATA block to prevent the line beak sequence from being interpreted as part of the xml? I'm not sure the SOAP API will handle it properly but worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

the [XML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends) requires that xml parsers normalize line endings to \0x0A. Given that SOAP uses XML its not going to be possible to preserve platform specific line endings. Possibly they would be preserved using the REST/JSON API instead.

Comment: Thanks superfell. When handing `\0x0A` through it's not stripped, it's just duplicated exactly. SO `$Signature = ("USER  \0x0A  Surname") ` produces `USER  \0x0A  Surname` in salesforce. You make a good point about switching to REST or JSON but want to exhaust this option first.

Comment: right, they're not stripped, the various line ending combos are all normalized to \0x0A, so you can't preserve a windows \r\n end of line sequence.